# Can I deposit a check into my account if it is not signed on the right hand side?

Tags: banking, check

I have a check made out to me by my son but he did not sign the check on the right side. Can I deposit it into my account? I plan to endorse the check on the back.

Comment: Are you saying that he didn't sign it at all, or that he did sign it, but not in the correct place?

Comment: Well, ask him to sign it. Is something preventing you from asking him to sign it? If the signature was left blank then it's possible they are purposely delaying the check for one reason or another. Do not forge a signature or else you would be committing a crime.

Comment: If this is a regular thing, look into online funds transfers in your/his banking website.  Some banks offer an app.   Checks/cheques are dying off in most of the world for good reasons.

Comment: See also: "I took a blank check out of someone's check book and wrote an amount on it, can I deposit it?"

Comment: To clarify, is this a regular check or a cashiers check? Cashiers check don't need a signature

Comment: Did your son intend for you to deposit it?

Comment: Banks are not obligated to accept unsigned checks. However, many banks are willing to accept one, provided the payee guarantees the check. To do this, the payee adds a line such as "lack of signature guaranteed" to his/her normal endorsement.

Answer (score 40):

Without a signature, there's not even a hint that your son meant to authorize the check.  The possibilities for fraud are endless.

That's why it **requires** his signature.  (I seriously doubt whether the bank would accept it.)

Answer (score 25):

Generally speaking if a check is not signed it is not valid and cannot be cashed or deposited. You should get your son to write a new one (or sign the one you have).

Comment: Why not just have him sign the current check??

Comment: @RonJohn Good point.

Comment: Could be a grown son that doesn't live near the OP.

Comment: @DJClayworth Also while this is technically correct, checks that are technically invalid are processed without issue *all the time*. Typically if the account has the funds, the only time there's an issue is if the check writer, or receiver, take action with the bank themselves. Not saying it's worth trying to cash/deposit it, potentially facing fees - just that OP may find themself considering it, and I hope they find the information useful

Comment: @TCooper You are not wrong, but they are also rejected all the time. I had a bank reject a check once because they thought the printed number in the middle did not match the digits for the amount on the right. Fortunately, I was able to just have the original person re-write a new check, but sometimes they do catch and act on errors much more minor than a lack of signature.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I'd argue the lack of a signature is more minor than amount not matching from the banks perspective. If they don't have a verified amount to move, they certainly don't want to move any money around. But very good point, especially to what I said about the account having the funds being the "only" reason. For good measure I'll repeat, I certainly don't recommend taking the 'try it anyway' route (and risking fees) - just acknowledging it happens often enough

Comment: I've seen someone that signs their signature like the little "X" you put down as "sign here", so his cheques get rejected all the time as "unsigned".

Answer (score 13):

A check without signature is just a worthless piece of paper. On the other hand, if you deposit it online, it might be processed automatically, and if your son doesn’t complain, it might just work.
Don’t try it though, it looks too much like a try on fraud. There is too much risk of getting needlessly in trouble.

Comment: Invalid cheques are not necessarily fraudulent. You won't get flagged for doing it once in a while (not that you should do it **deliberately**).